# Como usar atributos getElementsByTagName y setAttribute

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario de dos campos con quiero que cuando presione un boton ambos campos se coloquen de fondo rojo, hasta ahora tengo este codigo pero no funciona

```js
function validacion(){
var valor = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
valor.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
}
```

```html
    <form>
<input type="text" placeholder="texto" id="1" name="uno" class="caja"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="texto" id="2" name="dos" class="caja"/>
<input type="submit" value="aqui" onclick="return validacion()"/>
</form>
```

lo que pasa es que igual necesito que sea asignado a todos los input por eso utilizo el ***getElementByTagName***

Comment: La función `getElementsByTagName` te regresa un arreglo con los elementos que hayan hecho match con tu búsqueda, tienes que recorrer el arreglo con un ciclo e ir cambiando los estilos como los ocupas en tu ejemplo

Comment: Lo que pasa es que al hacer `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` este le devolverá un Array con todos los input que haya, y usted solo lo está asignando a una variable que no es de tipo Array.
Después de asignar eso a un Arra, lo que debe hacer es recorrerlo y hacer el cambio de color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que al hacer `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` este le devolverá un **`Array`** con todos los input que haya, y usted solo lo está asignando a una variable que no es de tipo **`Array`**. Después de asignar eso a un **`Array`**, lo que debe hacer es recorrerlo y hacer el cambio de color.

```js
function validacion(){
  let valor = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (let i = valor.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    valor[i].setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="texto" id="1" name="uno" class="caja"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="texto" id="2" name="dos" class="caja"/>
<input type="submit" value="aqui" onclick="return validacion()"/>
</form>
```

o como dijo el compañero

```
    function validacion(){
            for(var input of document.getElementsByTagName('input')){
                input.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
            }
         }
```

Comment: basta hacer `for(var input of document.getElementsByTagName('input'))`

Comment: Muchas gracias, la solucion me dio super no se si puedas explicarme o donde encuentro la explicacion de `input of document.getElementsByTagName`

Comment: @NestorBautista puedes buscar mas [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)